# Change the log language of DerbyDB/JPA

Tags: derby, glassfish-4

I'm using Eclipse to code a Java EE application. I deploy to Glassfish 4 AppServer. As DB I use the DerbyDB that is part of Glassfish.

My Eclipse is set up in English language.
But when I start the server (and Derby with it) I see this log:

```
    Starting database in Network Server mode on host 0.0.0.0 and port 1527.
--------- Informationen zu Derby Network Server --------
Version: CSS10090/10.9.1.0 - (1344872)  Build: 1344872  DRDA-Produkt-ID: CSS10090
-- listing properties --
derby.drda.traceDirectory=/home/kevin/workspace_pluginDev/.meta...
derby.drda.maxThreads=0
derby.drda.sslMode=off
derby.drda.keepAlive=true
derby.drda.minThreads=0
derby.drda.portNumber=1527
derby.drda.logConnections=false
derby.drda.timeSlice=0
derby.drda.startNetworkServer=false
derby.drda.host=0.0.0.0
derby.drda.traceAll=false
------------------ Java-Informationen ------------------
Java-Version: 1.7.0_25
Java-Anbieter: Oracle Corporation
Java-Home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Java-Klassenpfad: /home/kevin/glassfish4/glassfish/lib/asadmin/cli-optional.jar:/home/kevin/glassfish4/javadb/lib/derby.jar:/home/kevin/glassfish4/javadb/lib/derbytools.jar:/home/kevin/glassfish4/javadb/lib/derbynet.jar:/home/kevin/glassfish4/javadb/lib/derbyclient.jar
Name des Betriebssystems: Linux
Architektur des Betriebssystems: amd64
Betriebssystemversion: 3.8.0-29-generic
Java-Benutzername: kevin
Java-Benutzerausgangsverzeichnis: /home/kevin
Java-Benutzerverzeichnis: /home/kevin/glassfish4/glassfish
java.specification.name: Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.version: 1.7
java.runtime.version: 1.7.0_25-b30
--------- Derby-Informationen --------
[/home/kevin/glassfish4/javadb/lib/derby.jar] 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
[/home/kevin/glassfish4/javadb/lib/derbytools.jar] 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
[/home/kevin/glassfish4/javadb/lib/derbynet.jar] 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
[/home/kevin/glassfish4/javadb/lib/derbyclient.jar] 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
------------------------------------------------------
----------------- Informationen zur Ländereinstellung -----------------
Aktuelle Ländereinstellung:  [Deutsch/Deutschland [de_DE]]
Es wurde Unterstützung für die folgende Ländereinstellung gefunden: [cs]
     Version: 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
Es wurde Unterstützung für die folgende Ländereinstellung gefunden: [de_DE]
     Version: 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
Es wurde Unterstützung für die folgende Ländereinstellung gefunden: [es]
     Version: 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
Es wurde Unterstützung für die folgende Ländereinstellung gefunden: [fr]
     Version: 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
Es wurde Unterstützung für die folgende Ländereinstellung gefunden: [hu]
     Version: 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
Es wurde Unterstützung für die folgende Ländereinstellung gefunden: [it]
     Version: 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
Es wurde Unterstützung für die folgende Ländereinstellung gefunden: [ja_JP]
     Version: 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
Es wurde Unterstützung für die folgende Ländereinstellung gefunden: [ko_KR]
     Version: 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
Es wurde Unterstützung für die folgende Ländereinstellung gefunden: [pl]
     Version: 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
Es wurde Unterstützung für die folgende Ländereinstellung gefunden: [pt_BR]
     Version: 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
Es wurde Unterstützung für die folgende Ländereinstellung gefunden: [ru]
     Version: 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
Es wurde Unterstützung für die folgende Ländereinstellung gefunden: [zh_CN]
     Version: 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
Es wurde Unterstützung für die folgende Ländereinstellung gefunden: [zh_TW]
     Version: 10.9.1.0 - (1344872)
------------------------------------------------------

Starting database in the background.
Log redirected to /home/kevin/workspace_pluginDev/.metadata/.plugins/glassfish.javadb/derby.log.
Command start-database executed successfully.
```

So obviously Derby is in German language mode.

How can I change this, so that all logs are in English?

(Why is this important?:
Error messages are also in German. You will not find as much useful information when you search for German error messages, as you would with English ones.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Derby is simply using the basic Java locale support, as described here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/faq-jsp-138165.html

Run 'java -jar derbyrun.jar sysinfo', and look in the 'Locale Information' section of the output to determine what Locale Information Derby is receiving from the operating system.

On a Unix system, you should be able to controle the locale through the LANG environment variable, or by setting the user.language, user.country, and user.variant system properties from the command line.

Comment: I'll check those options. Btw: Is it possible to start derbyDB with parameters? It is started through glassfish.